# JQuery not working in html.erb file but works in Console

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Alright, so I have searched through a lot of relevant questions and tried the solutions, however, I am still unable to get this to work when I load it from my local machine using Google Chrome but it works when I copy and paste the script that is loaded in the browser page into the console.

I have a script as such in the html.erb code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click","#<%=parent_question.id%>_<%=trigger_option%>",function() {
      if($("#<%=parent_question.id%>_<%=trigger_option%>").prop('checked', true)){
        <% for i in child_options %>
          document.getElementById("<%=child_question.id%>").style.display = "block";
          document.getElementById("<%=child_question.id%>_<%=@option[i].id%>").style.display = "block";
        <%end%>
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Basically what this code does is dynamically creating scripts to display following questions and input fields depending on whether or not the someone selects Yes in the radio button from the previous question.

The following is a sample of a script when outputting into a browser:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on("click","#17_43",function() {
    if($("#17_43").prop('checked', true)){
      document.getElementById("18").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("18_45").style.display = "block";
    }
   });
 });
```

And the following HTML inputs and thingies it controls:

```
<p> Hello there :) </p>
<fieldset id="17">
   Yes
   <input type="radio" value="Yes" name="17" id="17_43">
   No
   <input type="radio" value="No" name="17" id="17_44">
</fieldset>
<p id="18" style="display: none;"> Thanks for helping!!! </p>
<input type="text" id="18_45" placeholder="HELLO" style="display: none;">
```

Any kind of help is much appreciated!

Comment: you have duplicated IDs. This is your first issue

Comment: Oh sorry that a remnant of a piece of code I did not change, thanks for pointing it out! Although it still does not work!

Comment: can you change this line **$("#17_43").prop('checked', true)** to **$("#17_43").is(':checked')**

Comment: I tried that previously and it breaks it even further where even if I copy and paste the script into the console, it doesn't work somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I fixed it, thanks to gaetanoM for pointing it out.

I had some conflicting IDs in the HTML code that I had not noticed causing some conflicts in executing the scripts, following that I noticed that due to that, part of my code which does the opposite when selecting the radio button that hides the input and question fields conflicted with the ID's and such.

Thanks so much for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

First, have you checked if the  tag is correctly populated where <%=...=> is placed?

Second, this isn't an answer to your problem, but I think you should use a different structure to do this.

Like on your html instead of rendering divs with "ids" of numbers, you would render divs with a class like "question" and add a data attribute such as "data-id", with data-id reflecting the question id to whatever fields, or "mark" the inputs with an id such as "checkbox_#{id}"

Then you can have a js file:

```
$('.question').on('click', function() {
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  if ($('#checkbox_'+id).prop('checked', true)){
    document.getElementById('p_'+id).style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('input_text_'+id).style.display = "block";
  }
});
```

If you're adding the questions and whatever dynamically, you might want to make a function that binds the click handler, like:

```
function bindQuestions() {
  $('.question').on('click', function() { 
     ........ 
  });
}
```

Then whenever you load new elements into the dom you can run "bindQuestions();"

Comment: Hmmm, I am not sure how this will work because I am dynamically loading in the questions and the options from the database.

Comment: Well, it works if you structure the rendered html correctly and then "bind" the loaded html, but since I am not seeing how you're rendering the html I can't help you further.